Couple crash at old hotel/motel and realize one is dead
If I remember correctly, this movie is rather old. I can´t guess at the year, but it´s most likely quite a bit before 2000.
A man and a woman are on a trip in the country, basically the middle of nowhere. They crash their car and take shelter at a motel or hotel. The people in the rooms around them have troubles- I think one room has a drug related couple where the man murders the woman in the bathtub?
The main man and woman try to ignore or escape from all the horrible things happening in the hotel, but the man (I think) notices pictures in the hotel of all the previous renters. The people in the pictures are dead, and the main couple has a picture up.
The man has to accept that he died in the crash for the woman to be able to continue living and leave the hotel. Or the woman is dead. At least one of them is.

Could it be "Farm House" (2008)?

"Beneath the Dark" (2010)

Driving to a wedding in Los Angeles through the Mojave Desert, Paul and Adrienne pull off the highway and into Roy's Motel and Cafe. This roadside artifact proves to be a strange and surreal place with an unsettling mix of travelers, who force our couple to discover the secret hidden between.




